# Load data from txt with pandas, columns seperated by ;

Tags: python, pandas, load, readfile, txt

I am trying to load a txt file containig a mix of various data. It also contains empty fields

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', header = None)
```

Structure of my input file:

```
column1;column2;column3;column4;column5;column6;column7;column8;column9;column10;column11
2011110602563790001;4445; ;B;-70.111;-2.630;0;1.7;2.4;1.1;3.555
```

Column3 mostly has no content

I tried to load the data in various ways but it doesn't seem to work with this txt. How can I load the text file with python? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot to precise the sep (find all parameters here : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Here is the code :

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', header = None, sep =';')
```

Comment: Hello Thomas Vivier, thank you very much! It turns out that i couldnt load the data due to an "ä" in the name of the file

Answer (score 1):

Try to define the delimiter:

```
pd.read_csv('data.txt', header = None, sep=";")
```

Comment: Hello Andre S., thank you very much! It turns out that i couldnt load the data due to an "ä" in the name of the file